# Hilbert scheme of 2 points on an elliptic curve

Tags: tag-removed, ag.algebraic-geometry, hilbert-schemes, elliptic-curves, algebraic-surfaces

The Hilbert scheme of 2 points on an elliptic curve $C$, $Hilb^2(C)$, has a natural structure of ruled surface, given by the map $f:Hilb^2(C) \to C$ such that $f(P,Q)=P+Q$.

What can we say about the corresponding locally free sheaf of rank 2 on $C$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case the corresponding locally free sheaf or rank $2$ on $C$ is the unique indecomposable one.

Comment: What is its degree?

Comment: Dimitri means that it is (up to translations) the unique nontrivial extension of degree 1 $1 \to \mathcal{O}_C→E→\mathcal{O}_C(o) \to 1$, where $o \in C$ is the origin in the group law.

Comment: Why is this true?

Comment: The curves of the form `$D_P=\{x+P \, | \, x \in C \}$` are a $1$-dimensional algebraic family of sections with self-intersection $1$, and moreover one cannot find two disjoint sections...